# How to perform data imputation when we have training, validation and test datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, data-imputation

I have a data set split in training, validation and test that I will use for training, validating and testing a classifier. We have missing or incorrect labels in all these folds and we are trying to use some techniques of data imputation for dealing with these problems. But I'm not sure how to use the data imputation in these folds.

My first idea was to use only training and validation datasets as the training data set for the data imputation technique. Once it was trained, I think that we can use it for fixing the values of the noisy samples in all folds (training, validation and test). I think that by doing this we could avoid data leakage. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think what you said makes sense. If you have the numbers to do so, by all means, use only training data for the imputation procedure. Then there might be some problem-specific things to keep in mind, but I believe you are correct.

Comment: Ideally, the imputation procedure should be included in each fold.  Otherwise, its effects are not measured by the cross-validation results, giving you an over-optimistic impression of the generalizability of your model.

Comment: what's your goal?